# Styling ASP.NET file uploader for different dimensions

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload, css

Is there any way to change the width of `ASP.NET file uploader`.
I tried adding the `CssClass` but unable to change the width. I just wondering is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Check this might help you : [Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can't change it directly some tricky solutions available like 
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload